# Flip string for LatLong vs LongLat

Tags: marklogic

The following Query is ok. But in a new situation, I get Lat/Long in stead of Long/Lat in the variable $point. Is there a way to flip the two parts within this string?

```
let $point  := fn:flip((52.2264, 6.8804) ... $point = (6.8804, 52.2264)
```

**Query**

```
let $polypoints  := $doc/k:coordinates/text()
let $poly        := cts:polygon($polypoints)
let $point       := cts:point(6.8804, 52.2264)

return (cts:polygon-contains($poly,$point, "coordinate-system=wgs84"))
```

**Coordinate data:**

```
<coordinates>6.8804,52.2264 6.8793,52.2257 6.8791,52.2256 6.879,52.2254 6.8788,52.2247 6.8787,52.2239 6.8786,52.2232 6.8786,52.2224 6.8786,52.2219 6.8786,52.2216 6.8786,52.2214 6.8787,52.2214 6.8803,52.2216 6.887,52.2223 6.8872,52.2223 6.8873,52.2223 6.8882,52.2224 6.8907,52.2226 6.8915,52.2227 6.8927,52.2229 6.8947,52.223 6.8957,52.2231 6.8993,52.2235 6.9003,52.2236 6.9045,52.224 6.9095,52.2245 6.9093,52.2246 6.9094,52.2247 6.9094,52.2248 6.9094,52.2253 6.9095,52.2255 6.9095,52.2263 6.9094,52.2268 6.9093,52.2271 6.9092,52.2274 6.9088,52.2278 6.9086,52.228 6.9083,52.2281 6.9079,52.2282 6.9076,52.2284 6.9073,52.2284 6.906,52.2286 6.905,52.2287 6.9044,52.2288 6.9041,52.2288 6.9039,52.2287 6.9037,52.2287 6.9035,52.2286 6.903,52.2284 6.9022,52.2281 6.9023,52.228 6.9014,52.2278 6.9004,52.2277 6.9003,52.2279 6.8982,52.2276 6.8978,52.2276 6.8963,52.2275 6.8948,52.2278 6.8946,52.2278 6.8924,52.2281 6.892,52.2282 6.8919,52.2282 6.8917,52.2283 6.8911,52.2284 6.8902,52.2285 6.8899,52.2286 6.8883,52.2281 6.8868,52.2276 6.8855,52.2274 6.8838,52.227 6.8829,52.2269 6.8825,52.2269 6.8819,52.2268 6.8815,52.2268 6.8812,52.2267 6.881,52.2266 6.8804,52.2264 </coordinates>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, is your intent to reverse the coordinates text  or to reverse your point ?
If your trying to reverse the coordinates of a single point -
You dont show how you get the cts:point, your example shows one constructed
by numbers.  In that case simply reverse the numbers so

```
let $point       := cts:point(6.8804, 52.2264)
```

becomes

```
let $point       := cts:point(52.2264,6.8804)
```

BUT your second point implies that the point comes from a string *somewhere* ...
Do you have control of that ?  Which is incorrect the coordinates or the point ?
Or does it matter ?

Your solution will work, assuming your point starts as text and you convert the *text*
prior to creating a cts:point()  - That is assuming its your point thats wrong.

Another solution similar which may or may not be more efficient is

```
let $pointtext := "6.8804, 52.2264"    --- Assuming your point starts as text ...
let $point := cts:point($pointtext) ,
    $point := cts:point(  cts:point-longitude($point) , cts:point-longitude) )
```

Another solution is to tokenize the string like this:

```
let $pointtext := "6.8804,52.2264"      (: Assuming your point comes from text beyond your control :)
let $latlong := fn:tokenize($pointtext,","),
    $point := cts:point($latlong[2]  cast as xs:double ,$latlong[1]  cast as xs:double )
```

Now your original question seems to imply your getting a point as a a sequence:
If your points are already sequences of 2 but reversed then an easy way is simply to reverse them
OR use them in reverse order like this: (not sure where you got fn:flip() from but assuming your asking for it  ... its fn:reverse)

So this answers your original question as posed:

```
let $pointrev := (52.2264, 6.8804)  , 
$point  := fn:reverse( $pointseq )
```

But of course that doesn't make a cts:point ... and so if you started with a pair of numbers in a sequence you don't need to reverse them just call cts:point with reversed args like

```
let $point := cts:point( $pointrev[2] , $pointrev[1] )
```

Now if your problem is the source data is reversed, the solutions are similar but reverse
This will flip the long/lat coordinates of a polygon  (assuming v7 .. otherwise use a for loop)

```
let $polypoints := $doc/coordinates/string()  (: USE string() NOT text() !!! trust me :)
let $poly := cts:polygon($polypoints)
let $newpoly := cts:polygon( 
  cts:polygon-vertices( $poly ) ! 
     cts:point( cts:point-longitude(.) , cts:point-latitude(.) ))
```

Overall I suggest
1) Try to get the input data correct in the first place
2) Avoid doing string parsing in XQuery if possible, its faster and more precise to 
  let the underlying code do it
3) If you using wgs84 then its important that the data is in the order because
  the world is not a perfect sphere so you may get different results by using reversed
  coordinates for some functions ... (or may not depending on what your doing ...)
4) Change as little data as possible.  If you have a huge map (say a million points)
   and testing only 1 point, just change that point (except if this violates #3)
   But if you test LOTS of points or your polygon is flipped you need to correct that ...
   which brings us back to #1 ... what is the source of the incorrect data ?
   By far the best solution is to fix the source .. because otherwise youll 
   probably find other things are broken too and you need to hack data in mysterious places,

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `cts:long-lat-point` constructor:

```
cts:long-lat-point("12,40") => 40,12
```

Answer (score 0):

What I use now:

```
  let $pa := fn:substring-after(fn:string($point), ",")
  let $pb := fn:substring-before(fn:string($point), ",")
  let $point := fn:concat($pa, ',', $pb)
```